# Roots of $x^{k+1}-x^k-n$

Tags: polynomials, galois-theory, roots

Suppose $n$ and $k$ are positive integers. Are there any known conditions on $n$ and $k$ such that the polynomial $x^{k+1}-x^k-n$ has rational or integer roots?

Comment: Every rational root of this polynomial must be an integer that divides $n$.

Comment: But this criterion is only useful if $n$ has not "too many" divisors which I would have to check. Is there anything else if $n$ is either to big to check all divisors or if I have multiple $n$ with similar form (e.g. all $n$ that only consist of the digit $5$) which I want to check?

Comment: Except the obvious fact that such a root is necessarily a divisor $d$ of $n$, which leads to  the observation  that $n$ must have the form $d^k(d-1)$ for some integer $d$, there's not much too say.

Answer (score 1):

It is a well-known fact (attribution?) that the rational roots of a polynomial with leading coefficient $a$ and constant term $b$ must be of the form $\pm \frac{p}{q}$, where $p$ divides $b$ and $q$ divides $a$. In your equation, the only possible rational roots are plus/minus factors of $n$. Let $m$ divide $n$ be a solution to your polynomial. We then have

$$ m^k(m-1) = n .$$

This equation states that $m^k$ is also a factor of $n$, along with $m-1$. We conclude that $n$ must have the form $m^k(m-1)$. As @Bernard notes, on top of this, there isn't too much to say.

Comment: Reference for the well-known fact: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem

Comment: @lhf how could I have forgotten that obvious name? Anyway, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Because of the [Rational Root Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem), every rational root $x=\frac{p}{q}$ of $x^{k+1}-x^k-n$ must satisfy $p\mid n$ and $q\mid 1$ in $\mathbb{Z}$. For most $k$, in practice, there will be no integer roots for given $n$ of the form $m^k(m-1)$.

As an example, let us consider $n=12$. Then only for $k=1$ we have an integer root:
\begin{align*}
x^2-x-12 &=(x+3)(x-4). \\
\end{align*}